# porque no puede leer el xml

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo

En el modulo de odoo que esoty editando estoy agregando un pop up pero hice que es pop up se muestre como una opcion del menu de otro modelo por lo cual hice la carpeta views en el modulo para poder hacer eso pero a la hora de actualizar los cambios me manda un error ya que dice que el id externo no existe yo pense que s eme habia paado ponerlo pero no

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<odoo>
<menuitem id="menu_mti_informe_cp_report"
              name="Informes(CP)"
              parent="stock.menu_stock_root"
              sequence="1"/>

<menuitem id="mti_informe_cp_report"
          parent="menu_mti_informe_cp_report"
          name="Informe Cartas Porte"
          action="mti_informe_cp"
          sequence="2"/>


</odoo>```



```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <odoo>
<record id="informe_cp_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Informe_cp</field>
    <field name="model">mti_informe_cp</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <field name="consignment_note_id" widget="Many2one_tags"/>
                <field name="print_type" widget="radio"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="get_informe_cp_report" string="PDF Report"
                        type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="get_excel_informe_cp_report" string="XLSX Report"
                        type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="mti_informe_cp_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Informe de carta porte</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">mti_informe_cp</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="informe_cp_wizard"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
````

```

ese es el codigo de xml que tengo en la carpeta views para poder visuali<zar su opcion en el menu pero justo es ahi donde la terminal manda el error que podria hacer ahí para que no lo mande ya que de igual forma lo tengo anexado al manifest

Adjunto imagen del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la verdad desconozco la razon del error que podria hacer para corregirlo ya que ese nombre de mti si lo tengo en el archivo python y en el xml del pop up ambos los tengo en la carpeta wizard pero no se porque razon no lo esta reconociendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner la estrucutra de tus carpetas?

Comment: Estas metiendo modulos dentro de modulos? Lo correcto sería tener todos esos modulos en la raíz.

Comment: estas separados o que pasa es que quiero ligar dos ya que uno es para reportes en especifico y el otro es para los reportes por defecto

Comment: Puedes mostrar el `act_windows` que tienes para mostrar el wizard?

Comment: listo ahi esta todo el xml que tengo en el wizard para la vista del popup

Comment: ambos codigos estan en el mismo modulo pero en diferentes carpetas uno esta en views y otro en wizard

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140911/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que está buscando dentro del modulo `mtl_report_cp`
algún xml con id `mtl_informe_cp`. Según el código que muestras, debe ser una acción pero parece que la tienes dentro de otro modulo. En ese caso debería ser así:

Corrige este id. Esta repetido contra el `act_window` y cambia el id del action por el que verdaderamente tiene.

```xml
<menuitem id="menu_mti_informe_cp_report"
          parent="menu_2_mti_informe_cp_report"
          name="Informe Cartas Porte"
          action="mti_informe_cp_report"
          sequence="2"/>
```

Suponiendo que el action este en el mismo modulo, deberia funcionar así.

```
<record id="mti_informe_cp_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Informe de carta porte</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">mti_informe_cp</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

Comment: de echo ahi iria el modelo que quiero abrir en la carpeta wizard no? entonces seria el nombre del modelo o el nombre asi como tal wizard.mti_informe_cp

Comment: No. el campo `action` señala al id de una registro tipo `act_window`. En ese registro va el modelo y el dominio y/o demas configuraciones para llamar a la vista.

Comment: @CarlosBaez Revisa las ediciones a la respuesta.

Comment: pone que se detecto una recurrencia

Comment: listo  ya pude corregirlo pero ahor amanda un error relacionado con informe_cp  @Legna

Comment: en la terminal manda un key error: informe_cp @Legna

Comment: listo ya funciono mil gracias solo reinstale el modulo